# What happens when PM2 gets overloaded?

Tags: node.js, pm2

So there I was with my new 32 core Dell PowerEdge and I wanted to see how many requests a 32 core PM2 cluster could handle.

So, I created my simple server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer((request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("hi :)");
}).listen(8000);
```

And smacked it with Apache Benchmark:

```
ab -c 1000 -n 5000000 http://10.0.0.10:8000/
```

I know a single core on average hardware with average concurrency on `ab` can handle about `4,000`, so surely 4,000 x 32 on max concurrency should be a really mind blowing number. Well, it wasn't; it was `12,365`.

It quickly became clear to me that the pm2 master process was maxed out and the rest were about 7-9%. See here:

[image: pm2]

What can be done about this? If nothing, is it just that I've created a really impractical example and this is a situation that an ordinary application is unlikely to encounter? Or is this a legitimate limitation of this tool (pm2)?

Comment: Try running PM2 in [debug mode](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#contributing-development-mode) to see what it's doing. Also, make sure that you're not running it in watch mode.

Comment: Could you try by using the cluster module directly and do the same benchmark? https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/

Comment: @tknew I saw average CPU usage for the workers go up slightly, to about 10-12% each. I'm guessing this is a result of removing the overhead of pm2. But I guess this kind of answers my question. The problem is present after removing pm2, so I suppose that makes it a cluster module limitation.

Comment: Interesting results, I guess this can be due to system limitations too. I wonder what would happen if we put Nginx front of 32 node.js processes

Comment: @tknew I'll try that today. It'll be fun.

Comment: @tknew I just finished that test. I ultimately reached NIC saturation. Nginx kept creating new processes to handle the ever increasing load of connections. It was running about 8 nginx processes at 60-70% and 32 node processes at 30-32%. I'm sure there was some context switching in there wearing it down. It took three computers hitting it with 1024 concurrent connections. I did manage to get a combined 107k requests/second; so there's that.